# How to drop conflicted rows in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a cliassification task, which means the conflicts harm the performance, i.e. same feature but different label.

```py
idx feature label
 0     a      0
 1     a      1
 2     b      0
 3     c      1
 4     a      0
 5     b      0
```

How could I get formated dataframe as below?

```py
idx feature label
 2    b       0
 3    c       1
 5    b       0
```

`Dataframe.duplicated()` only output the duplicated rows, it seems the logic operation between `df["features"].duplicated()` and `df.duplicated()` do not return the results I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need rows with only one unique value per groups - so use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html), compare by `1` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('feature')['label'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
print (df)
   idx feature  label
2    2       b      0
3    3       c      1
5    5       b      0
```